# Multiplying values of cells returning nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that loops over rows and captures the values in certain cells. It successfully does that, and I am able to return those individual values even. However when I try and multiple them it returns nothing. Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khemikal/12hn2uhv/4/)

Here is my function:

```
$('#' + value + ' .totalRacks').each(function() {
  $.each(this.cells, function() {
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    var prevRow0 = $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td:nth-child(' + index + ')');
    var prevRow1 = $(this).closest('tr').prev().prev().prev().find('td:nth-child(' + index + ')');
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(prevRow0.text()))) {
      var td1 = parseInt(prevRow0.text());
    }
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(prevRow1))) {
      var td2 = parseInt(prevRow1);
    }
    var product = parseInt((td1 * td2));
    $(this).html(product);
  });
});
```

Comment: You have a simple mistake in the second `if`-body: `var td2 = parseInt(prevRow1);` --- you are not taking the `text()` value of that like in the first `if`. Same in the `if` condition.

Comment: hmm added that but still no cigar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of logic issues. Firstly you can loop through the `td` cells using a single `each()` call and you missed the retrieval of the `text()` of the `prevRow1`. If you fix those issues the code works. You can also tidy the `isNaN` checks by defaulting the values to `0`. Try this:

```
$('#' + value + ' .totalRacks td:not(:first, :last)').each(function() {
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    var prevRow0 = $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td:nth-child(' + index + ')');
    var prevRow1 = $(this).closest('tr').prev().prev().prev().find('td:nth-child(' + index + ')');

    var td1 = parseInt(prevRow0.text(), 10) || 0;
    var td2 = parseInt(prevRow1.text(), 10) || 0;    
    var product = parseInt(td1 * td2);
    $(this).html(product);
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/12hn2uhv/12/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.totalRacks').each(function() {
  $.each(this.cells, function() {
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    var prevRow0 = $(this).closest('tr').prev().find('td:nth-child(' + index + ')');
    var prevRow1 = $(this).closest('tr').prev().prev().prev().find('td:nth-child(' + index + ')');
    var td1 = parseInt(prevRow0.text());
    var td2 = parseInt(prevRow1.text());
    var product = parseInt((td1 * td2));
    $(this).html(product);
  });
});
```

```css
.table-style {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 15px;
  /*height: 320px;*/
  /*margin: auto;*/
  /*max-width: 600px;*/
  /*padding: 5px;*/
  /*width: 100%;*/
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  animation: float 5s infinite;
}
th {
  color: #D5DDE5;
  background: #333;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #9ea7af;
  border-right: 1px solid #343a45;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 7px;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  vertical-align: middle;
}
th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}
th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-right: none;
}
tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
  color: #666B85;
  font-size: 5px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.1);
}
tr:hover td {
  background: #444;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #22262e;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #22262e;
}
tr:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}
tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
  background-color: #333333;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  /*background:#EBEBEB;*/
}
tr:nth-child(odd):hover td {
  background: #444;
}
tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
/*grand total color*/

#sumLw > tbody > tr:last-child > td {
  color: #D5DDE5;
  background: #333333 !important;
}
#sumWtd > tbody > tr:last-child > td {
  color: #D5DDE5;
  background: #333333 !important;
}
#sumStd > tbody > tr:last-child > td {
  color: #D5DDE5;
  background: #333333 !important;
}
#catSumLw > tbody > tr:last-child > td {
  color: #D5DDE5;
  background: #333333 !important;
}
#catSumWtd> tbody > tr:last-child > td {
  color: #D5DDE5;
  background: #333333 !important;
}
#catSumStd > tbody > tr:last-child > td {
  color: #D5DDE5;
  background: #333333 !important;
}
#mvpWtd > tbody > tr:last-child > td {
  color: #D5DDE5;
  background: #333333 !important;
}
#mvpStd > tbody > tr:last-child > td {
  color: #D5DDE5;
  background: #333333 !important;
}
/*hide some mvp columns */

/*#mvpWtd > tbody > td:nth-child(6) {
    display: none;
}*/

td {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-right: 1px solid #C1C3D1;
}
td:last-child {
  border-right: 0px;
}
th.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}
th.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
th.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
td.text-left {
  text-align: left;
}
td.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
td.text-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-style" id="rackPlan0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Store Trait</th>
      <th>PROTO A</th>
      <th>PROTO B</th>
      <th>PROTO C</th>
      <th>PROTO D</th>
      <th>PROTO E</th>
      <th>PROTO F</th>
      <th>PROTO G</th>
      <th>PROTO H</th>
      <th>PROTO I</th>
      <th>PROTO J</th>
      <th>PROTO K</th>
      <th>PROTO L</th>
      <th>PROTO M</th>
      <th>PROTO N</th>
      <th>PROTO O</th>
      <th>PROTO P</th>
      <th>PROTO Q</th>
      <th>PROTO R</th>
      <th>PROTO S</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="storeCount">
      <td>Store Count</td>
      <td class="protoA">5</td>
      <td class="protoB">8</td>
      <td class="protoC">39</td>
      <td class="protoD">110</td>
      <td class="protoE">329</td>
      <td class="protoF">408</td>
      <td class="protoG">642</td>
      <td class="protoH">542</td>
      <td class="protoI">393</td>
      <td class="protoJ">309</td>
      <td class="protoK">291</td>
      <td class="protoL">171</td>
      <td class="protoM">302</td>
      <td class="protoN">120</td>
      <td class="protoO">166</td>
      <td class="protoP">67</td>
      <td class="protoQ">18</td>
      <td class="protoR">10</td>
      <td class="protoS">5</td>
      <td class="totalRow">3,935</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="runningStore">
      <td class="totalText"></td>
      <td class="protoA"></td>
      <td class="protoB"></td>
      <td class="protoC"></td>
      <td class="protoD"></td>
      <td class="protoE"></td>
      <td class="protoF"></td>
      <td class="protoG"></td>
      <td class="protoH"></td>
      <td class="protoI"></td>
      <td class="protoJ"></td>
      <td class="protoK"></td>
      <td class="protoL"></td>
      <td class="protoM"></td>
      <td class="protoN"></td>
      <td class="protoO"></td>
      <td class="protoP"></td>
      <td class="protoQ"></td>
      <td class="protoR"></td>
      <td class="protoS"></td>
      <td class="totalRow"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="racksPerStore">
      <td>Racks/Store</td>
      <td class="protoA">279</td>
      <td class="protoB">270</td>
      <td class="protoC">246</td>
      <td class="protoD">257</td>
      <td class="protoE">236</td>
      <td class="protoF">215</td>
      <td class="protoG">204</td>
      <td class="protoH">189</td>
      <td class="protoI">225</td>
      <td class="protoJ">178</td>
      <td class="protoK">166</td>
      <td class="protoL">151</td>
      <td class="protoM">140</td>
      <td class="protoN">121</td>
      <td class="protoO">108</td>
      <td class="protoP">94</td>
      <td class="protoQ">84</td>
      <td class="protoR">67</td>
      <td class="protoS">62</td>
      <td class="totalRow">3292</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="totalRacks">
      <td class="totalText">Total Racks</td>
      <td class="protoA"></td>
      <td class="protoB"></td>
      <td class="protoC"></td>
      <td class="protoD"></td>
      <td class="protoE"></td>
      <td class="protoF"></td>
      <td class="protoG"></td>
      <td class="protoH"></td>
      <td class="protoI"></td>
      <td class="protoJ"></td>
      <td class="protoK"></td>
      <td class="protoL"></td>
      <td class="protoM"></td>
      <td class="protoN"></td>
      <td class="protoO"></td>
      <td class="protoP"></td>
      <td class="protoQ"></td>
      <td class="protoR"></td>
      <td class="protoS"></td>
      <td class="totalRow"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```